# JBoss, Upgrade Infinispan 7.2.5

Tags: linux, jboss, infinispan

I have infinispan 6.0, want to upgrade it to 7.2.5, and keep the config files same, but upgrade the binaries.

Comment: I'm using these on RHEL 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Parsers for 6.x-style configuration have been dropped. If you insist on using old configuration files, you have to write your own parser (or rather port the parser from 6.0 to changes in programmatic API).

Another option is to use commmercial JDG 6.6 which includes most of the features from 7.2.5 but still uses the old configuration format for compatibility.

Updating your config is the easiest way.